# Connect4 falling animation

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, jbutton

I'm new to GUI and I've heard about `Timer` but I'm not sure how I will apply it to animate the falling motion of a token when the user clicks on one of the drop buttons at the top of the panel.

As of the moment I'm only using `setIcon()` to change one of the empty circles on the board to the color of the current player whenever the player takes his/her turn.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
//1 is for green, 2 is for red
//Set icon. Know where to place first from setPosition.

public void setToken(int token, int i, int j){  
    if (token == 1){
        buttonArray[i][j].setIcon (greentoken);
        if (active == GREEN){
            active = RED;
        }else if (active == RED){
            active = GREEN;
    }
    }else if (token == 2){
        buttonArray[i][j].setIcon (redtoken);
        if (active == GREEN){
            active = RED;
        }else if (active == RED){
            active = GREEN;
        }
    }
}
//Position checker. 
//Invoked by checkColFull().
//checkColFull() called after a drop button is clicked and checks if column is full.

public void setPosition(int column){
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; ++row){
        if (slots[row][column] > 0)
            break;
    }
    if (row > 0){
        //save
        slots[--row][column] = active;  
        setToken(active, row, column);
    }
}
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
    //Buttons
        else if (e.getSource () == b1){
            checkColFull (0);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b2){
            checkColFull(1);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b3){
            checkColFull(2);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b4){
            checkColFull(3);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b5){
            checkColFull(4);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b6){
            checkColFull (5);
        }
        else if (e.getSource () == b7){
            checkColFull(6);
        }
}
```

*If the code snippet I provided isn't enough please someone do tell me.*

Will I have to scrap everything to achieve the falling token animation I'm after? Any hints?

Comment: Please put those buttons in some kind of array, so you don't have to write the same code 7 times over!

Comment: @DavidWallace Yep thought of that before but I just somehow have forgotten to change it bc busy but okay thanks :)